# mongos chunksize error in mongo 3.4.2

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have mongo version 3.4.2 and I have the following command:

```
mongos --configdb localhost:27016 --chunkSize 1 --port 27020
```

It doesn't work in my version of mongo. Could somebody help to solve it? 
I don't want to degrade to previous version of mongo by the way.
It used to work under the previous versions (ex. 3.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `--chunkSize` option anymore.

From 3.4 release notes:

> > MongoDB 3.4 removes the following configuration options from the mongos:
> >     sharding.chunkSize configuration file setting and --chunkSize command-line option
> >     sharding.autoSplit configuration file setting and --noAutoSplit command line option

You will have to use the procedure described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/modify-chunk-size-in-sharded-cluster/) in order to modify the chunk size:

```
use config
db.settings.save( { _id:"chunksize", value: 1 } )
```

Comment: shoudl i do it in my shard server?

Comment: Using `mongos`. Connect same as described above, but without the `--chunkSize` option, then follow as described above.